# Как объединить несколько svg в один холст

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт

Как объединить несколько svg в один svg наиболее простым и правильным способом?
Например, у меня есть вот такой набор svg:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.867 53.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path fill="#efce4a"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.867 53.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path fill="#efce4a"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.867 53.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path fill="#efce4a"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.867 53.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path fill="#efce4a"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.867 53.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path fill="#efce4a"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
</svg>

<br>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55.867 55.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path
      fill="#efce4a"
      d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55.867 55.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path
      fill="#efce4a"
      d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55.867 55.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path
      fill="#efce4a"
      d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55.867 55.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path
      fill="#efce4a"
      d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55.867 55.867" height="20" width="20">
  <path
      fill="#efce4a"
      d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
</svg>
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы вместо десяти svg у меня это была один целый svg. Что-то вроде такого:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.867 53.867" height="50" width="150">

  <g height="20" width="20" x="0" y="0">
  <path fill="#efce4a"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" h="0" y="30">
    <path fill="#efce4a"
          d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="0" y="60">
    <path fill="#efce4a"
          d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="0" y="90">
    <path fill="#efce4a"
          d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="0" y="120">
    <path fill="#efce4a"
          d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/>
  </g>

  <br>

  <g height="20" width="20" x="30" y="0">
    <path
        fill="#efce4a"
        d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="30" y="30">
    <path
        fill="#efce4a"
        d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="30" y="60">
    <path
        fill="#efce4a"
        d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="30" y="90">
    <path
        fill="#efce4a"
        d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
  </g>
  <g height="20" width="20" x="30" y="120">
    <path
        fill="#efce4a"
        d="M11.287 54.548a.997.997 0 0 1-.985-1.169l3.091-18.018L.302 22.602a1.001 1.001 0 0 1 .555-1.705l18.09-2.629 8.091-16.393a.996.996 0 1 1 1.792 0l8.09 16.393 18.091 2.629a1.002 1.002 0 0 1 .555 1.705L42.475 35.363l3.09 18.017c.064.375-.09.754-.397.978a.993.993 0 0 1-1.054.076l-16.18-8.506-16.182 8.506a1.008 1.008 0 0 1-.465.114zM3.149 22.584l12.016 11.713a1 1 0 0 1 .287.885L12.615 51.72l14.854-7.808a.996.996 0 0 1 .931 0l14.852 7.808-2.836-16.538a1 1 0 0 1 .287-.885l12.016-11.713-16.605-2.413a1 1 0 0 1-.753-.547L27.934 4.578l-7.427 15.047a1 1 0 0 1-.753.547L3.149 22.584z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT есть подозрение, что это проще всего сделать в том же редакторе, где было нарисовано ;-)

Comment: @UModeL ты прав, было бы проще, но похоже это будет звёздный рейтинг, поэтому отдельными клонами, объектами будет удобнее манипулировать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Элементы svg повторяются, поэтому их можно клонировать с помощью
  команды `<use>`.
- Так как размеры полотна svg и `viewBox` рассчитаны на одну фигуру
  svg, в исходном примере, то поэтому их необходимо увеличить размеры
  полотна, чтобы входило два ряда звездочек по пять звёзд в одном ряду.

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 135"  width="120" height="50">`

Звёздочки второго ряда,в исходном примере, нарисованы **двойным контуром**, поэтому, не будет возможности их перекрашивать с помощью правил css. См. рисунок ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому я выбрал одинаковые звёздочки для обоих рядов, но с разными атрибутами закраски.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 135"  width="120" height="50">
  <defs>
    <path id="star_Y" fill="#efce4a" stroke="#efce4a" stroke-width="2"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/> 
  <path id="star_W" stroke="#efce4a" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
        d="M26.934 1.318l8.322 16.864 18.611 2.705L40.4 34.013l3.179 18.536-16.645-8.751-16.646 8.751 3.179-18.536L0 20.887l18.611-2.705z"/> 
     
  </defs>
  <!-- Первый ряд звёзд -->
  <use xlink:href="#star_Y" x="-90" />
    <use xlink:href="#star_Y" x="-30" />
  <use xlink:href="#star_Y" x="30" />
    <use xlink:href="#star_Y" x="90" />
     <use xlink:href="#star_Y" x="150" />  
  
      <!-- Второй ряд звёзд -->
  <use xlink:href="#star_W" x="-90" y="60" />
    <use xlink:href="#star_W" x="-30" y="60" />
  <use xlink:href="#star_W" x="30" y="60"/>
    <use xlink:href="#star_W" x="90" y="60" />
     <use xlink:href="#star_W" x="150" y="60" />   
</svg>
```

Comment: Как оказывается просто! Спасибо! Хм, use - полезная штука.

Comment: @kizoso и вам спасибо за вопрос, совсем мало интересных вопросов стало.

Answer (score 4):

Я конечно понимаю, что это не по теме, я только хотел показать насколько просто иногда рисовать при помощи `d3` =)

```js
let row = 20, pad = 30, hover;

let d = Array(100).fill(0).map((d, i) => ({
  color: `hsl(${i*3}, 66%, 66%)`,
  i: i,
  x: pad/2 + (i%row)*pad,
  y: pad/2 + Math.floor(i/row)*pad
}));

let stars = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(d)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d3.symbol().size(300).type(d3.symbolStar))
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
  .attr('stroke', d => d.color)
  .on('mousemove', hoverFun)
  .on('mouseover', hoverFun)
  .on('click', d=>console.log(d.color))

function hoverFun(d) {
  if (hover && this === hover.node())
    return;
  hover && hover.transition().duration(200).attr('fill-opacity', 1)
  hover = d3.select(this);
  hover.transition().duration(100).attr('fill-opacity', 0)
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  stars.each(d => d.i += 1)
       .attr('transform',  d => `rotate(${d.i} ${d.x},${d.y}) translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="640" height="175"></svg>
```

PS: Как правильно заметил Alexandr_TT в комментариях, надо бы добавить ссылку на генератор символов, который тут использован для создания звездочки [`d3-shape#symbol`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbol)

Comment: всё просто, когда хорошо владеешь темой :) добавлю ссылку по [d3.symbol](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbol)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а Вы знаете про суперформулу? =)

Comment: только собираюсь узнать :)) Можно на ты, так короче. Сделай самоответ, думаю будет полезно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT прости, но я вполне привык, много деловой переписки на работе приходится вести...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT может быть созрею, но в 2х словах это математическое уравнение в полярных координатах, меняя в нем коэффициенты можно получить много разных концентрических фигур, в том числе и звездочку =)  https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/ywJrMJ